# How to index columns created by django-modeltranslation to Elastic, using django-elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: django, django-models, elasticsearch-py, django-modeltranslation, django-model-field

I've translated my Model fields with [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) and implemented search using [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl).

Problem:
django-modeltranslation creates translation fields in DB, and not in my Models, and search is working only for fields created by Model. As django-elasticsearch-dsl is checking Models to rebuild search index.

When I try:

> python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild

I get the error:

```
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/apps.py", line 14, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/__init__.py", line 11, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('documents')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/barbos/django-symbolsite/symbolgraph/search/documents.py", line 7, in <module>
    class SymbolDocument(Document):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/registries.py", line 65, in register_document
    field_instance = document.to_field(field_name, django_field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 142, in to_field
    "to an Elasticsearch field!".format(field_name)
django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ModelFieldNotMappedError: Cannot convert model field name_ru to an Elasticsearch field!
Oleh-MacSymbol-Pro:symbolgraph barbos$ python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 138, in to_field
    model_field.__class__](attr=field_name)
KeyError: <class 'modeltranslation.fields.field_factory.<locals>.TranslationFieldSpecific'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/apps.py", line 14, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/__init__.py", line 11, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('documents')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/barbos/django-symbolsite/symbolgraph/search/documents.py", line 7, in <module>
    class SymbolDocument(Document):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/registries.py", line 65, in register_document
    field_instance = document.to_field(field_name, django_field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 142, in to_field
    "to an Elasticsearch field!".format(field_name)
django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ModelFieldNotMappedError: Cannot convert model field name_ru to an Elasticsearch field!
```

Django 3.0.5
django-modeltranslation & django-elasticsearch-dsl - latest versions
elasticsearch-7.6.2
db.sqlite3 (I'm going to migrate to PostgreSQL)

related django files:

```
#settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
    'search',
    'symbol',
    'category',
    'homepage',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

ELASTICSEARCH_DSL={
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}

---
#translation.py
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from .models import Symbol

class SymbolTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', 'content', 'meaning', 'tag',)

translator.register(Symbol, SymbolTranslationOptions)

---
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.constraints import UniqueConstraint
class Symbol(models.Model): 
    id  = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True) #uniqe
    codepoint = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True) #this list should be in separete table
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    show_in_category = models.BooleanField()
    popular = models.BooleanField(blank=True, unique=False, default=False)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)  #this list should be in separete table
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    meaning = models.TextField(blank=True)
    imgslug = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=255, blank=True) #uniqe
    # name_en = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    # name_ru = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    # tag_en = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    # tag_ru = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    # content_en = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # content_ru = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # meaning_en = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # meaning_ru = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

---
#documents.py
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from symbol.models import Symbol


@registry.register_document
class SymbolDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        # Name of the Elasticsearch index
        name = 'symbols'
        # See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Symbol # The model associated with this Document

        # The fields of the model you want to be indexed in Elasticsearch
        fields = [
            'symbol',
            'name',
            'tag',
            'content',
            'meaning',
            'shortcode',
            'codepoint',
            'slug',
            'id',
            #
            # 'name_ru',
            # 'name_uk',
            # 'tag_ru',
            # 'tag_uk',
            # 'content_ru',
            # 'content_uk',
            # 'meaning_ru',
            # 'meaning_uk',
            # 'also_called_ru',
            # 'also_called_uk',
        ]
```

I found one bad way to make search work in other languages:

1. Disable django-modeltranslation in INSTALLED APPS.
2. Add all fields created in DB by django-modeltranslation in the Model.
3. Add these fields to documents.py in search app to ceate Index for Elastic and restart django server
4. Check if "$ python3 manage.py makemigrations" returns: "No changes detected".
5. $ python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild
6. Revert steps 3, 2, 1 and restart django server

I need to include the translations into the Elasticsearch indexes.
As a noob in development I don't know what to do next.

I have a two ideas(more like a direction), but don't know how to implement:

- Change django-elasticsearch-dsl to index from DB directly.
- Change django-modeltranslation to be abble to add fields it creates in DB to the Model.

Comment: Having the same problem with GinIndex + Django modeltranslation in Postgres trigram search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the fields in the `Document` class explicitly. Like following

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import TextField

@registry.register_document
class SymbolDocument(Document):
    name_ru = TextField()
    ....
```

Comment: What would the solution look like for Django with ordinary postgres indexes used in trigram search, e.g. GinIndex or GistIndex?

Comment: @Daniel did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same thing

Comment: @Yorbjörn I faced the error only on `manage.py makemigrations`, so I ended up creating a manual migration with needed indexes. I could share the code if you're willing to open a SO question :) Would appreciate!